# What is the meaning of 'Instagrammification' and 'instagrammify'?

Tags: meaning

I read some post saying Instagrammification. What does it mean? Which situation is it used? Also, what is the meaning the similar word 'Instagrammify'?

Comment: This is fairly normal "casual" style -- to take the name of, eg, some popular web tool, treat it as a verb, and, often, add suffixes to enhance it's "verbiness".  Hence "Google" is used as a verb, and people occasionally use ["Googlify"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=googlify) to refer to changing a web site to resemble Google.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an obscure formulation of the word Instagram. When I google it, I see some obscure blog articles like this one: https://dayoneperspective.com/the-instagrammification-of-restaurants-bade2ed5721e

As for a specific definition, here's my best attempt: "To create more focus on visual aesthetic and photography within a physical space or group activity, for the purpose of sharing the experience on Instagram."

It is easy to understand the word in context but a little tricky to pin down with a concise definition. I'm curious if anybody else can do a better job than what I came up with.